# Assembling 32 bit x86 code with gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, x86, sdl

I'm trying to get [sdl quake](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/quake/) to build on my 64 bit linux system. It builds and runs fine on my 32 bit linux system. The error that I am getting is:

```
d_copy.S:28: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
```

Along with a bunch of similar errors. I'm assuming that I should be able to just build with the -m32 flag, and it will build it as a 32 bit binary. That's fine with me.

I appended "-m32" to the CFLAGS in the Makefile, and tried to build again, but now I get:

```
gcc -DPACKAGE=\"sdlquake\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.9\"  -I. -I.      
-g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -DSDL -DELF -m32 -c cd_sdl.c
In file included from /usr/include/SDL/SDL_main.h:26:0,
             from /usr/include/SDL/SDL.h:30,
             from cd_sdl.c:8:
/usr/include/SDL/SDL_stdinc.h:34:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [cd_sdl.o] Error 1
```

I think I might just be missing something obvious here, as I haven't played around with the -m32 flag that much. OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You need 32-bit version of `libc-dev` to do that.

The fastest way with Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386`